# linux shared folder for all users php not working mod_hive suexec

Tags: apache-2.4, share, symlink, suexec

Feel free to educate me - I'm migrating from a windows server to a dedicated linux server with apache 2.4 and centos 6.10 ... all users on the server are actually ME, so this part is not a security concern.

I want to share a folder to all users. I finally got this partially working with symlinks - it works for linking to static files, but won't work for php includes, which I need.

After talking to my hosting company, and asking about perhaps using bind --mount to achieve this, I learned that mod_hive and suexec are not going to allow this. They said I need to " disable the hive module and set up a clean apache installation" to make this work. If I understand correctly, I'd be disabling built-in security features that I should probably keep.

Is there another way, without making my server less secure?

I really need the ability for all users to include files from a shared folder - we have certain products that change specs all the time, and when I need to update those specs I don't want to update dozens of files.

Comment: Unsure about the hive portion, but could you simply modify the PHP `include_path` to include a common directory?  You may need some generic user that is a member of a group that includes all users, etc. for the `suexec` portion of the issue to own the files...

Comment: thanks ivanivan. I tried that. Permission denied. I'm pretty sure hive is the problem there but I honestly don't understand it well.

Comment: CentOS 6 will be EOL in a little more than a year. As a general rule you should not start new projects on old OSes. And web sites almost always should run the latest available OS.